# Is a Preloader needed for an fully self-contained Flash SWF application?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

So, I'm hoping to get some clarification on a topic that has lots of answers, but I'm trying to determine the right one for my situation.

If I'm developing a fully self-contained FLASH CS5.5/6. CC application that I'm intending to release to the mobile and web markets... and all the library elements are contained in the single FLA and resulting SWF file.

My question is...

Do I need to Pre-load anything with a Pre-Loader or Loader?
I see a lot of advice for Pre-loader and loaders and they work great, but it appears these are only needing for pulling in SWFs or items outside the confines of the master SWF... but nothing seems to indicate that a pre-loader is necessary for a self-contained SWF.

Also, if someone could post some architecture advice and say if there is anything wrong with keeping it self-contained, that would be helpful as well.

Looking forward to gaining some clarity on this subject.  I wish the community well.  Thank you!

Best regards,

FloridaBoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When compiling an SWF with Flash IDE, the resulting file has your assets embedded into the swf.  In this scenario, you don't need a preloader because they're already in memory when your SWF is opened.  Assets that are not included in you SWF are what require loading, and why preloading data into memory (rather than on-demand) would benefit perceived performance.

However, it is naive to believe that because it's all compiled into your SWF that it will bypass the loading time required of external assets.  The application still has to load all your embedded assets into memory, and this typically results in a longer pause at the start of the application as it loads.

Additionally, the smallest of changes (such as modifying a line of code, or tweaking an image) will require a complete recompile of your SWF.  If you have many assets, and want the freedom of updating these individually, you'll want your assets externalized.  This will significantly reduce your compile times, and increase the stability of your FLA file (which can often inexplicably become borked).  In fact, for this reason alone, you might consider doing zero code in Flash IDE, and use external AS files [edited](http://www.sublimetext.com/) in [better](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) [programs](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex.html), and relegate the IDE to compile/debug only.  Even then, there are [great ancillary applications](http://www.demonsterdebugger.com/) for [debugging](https://creative.adobe.com/products/scout).

Comment: Thank you for the rapid response, Atriace.  It is kind of what I thought, but wanted to confirm.  I am indeed not coding in Flash itself, but rather FlashDevelop.  I understand the reason for keeping some things external when doing lot of heavy transition that could be memory intensive.  I will have to monitor this in my app as I code along and sub out things as needed.  Thank you for the direction and advice.  FloridaBoy :)